# Laravel not taking my Database Input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-form

I'm trying to insert entries in database table but it's not working. It was working 2 weeks ago but I thing I have accidentally changed something.

my relevant model, migration and controllers are here

Model - Profile.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table='profile';

    protected $fillable=['user_id', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Address'];
}
```

Migration -

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfileTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
            Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->char('Gender', 1);
            $table->string('Age')->unique();
            $table->string('Address');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Controller - profileController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Profile;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
//use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class profileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(){


        return view('pages.profile');
    }

    public function store(){
        $uid=Auth::user()->id;
        $input=Request::all();
        $input['user_id']=$uid;
        $profile = new Profile(array('user_id'=>$uid, 'gender'=>$input['gender'], 'age'=>$input['age'], 'address'=>$input['address']));
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

The page with form - pages/profile.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4')) !!}
<!-- <form class="form-horizontal col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4 ">-->
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>User Profile</legend>

<!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="gender-0">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-0" value="1" checked="checked">
      Male
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="gender-1">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-1" value="2">
      Female
    </label>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="age">Age</label>  
  <div class="col-md-2">
  <input id="age" name="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="address">Address</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address">Address</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
<!--</form>-->
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Also, just in case, my route.php -

```
Route::get('profile', 'profileController@index');
Route::post('profile', 'profileController@store');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your migration, you use uppercase column names (i.e. "Gender"), whereas you use lowercase ("gender") when you try to fill your model. Also, you never save your model:

```
$profile = new Profile(array('user_id'=>$uid, 'Gender'=>$input['gender'], 'Age'=>$input['age'], 'Address'=>$input['address']));    
$profile->save(); // <- You need to call save() to persist the model to your database.
return view('welcome');
```

Comment: After using $profile->save(); I'm getting this error - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `profile` (`user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3, 2015-12-04 16:28:40, 2015-12-04 16:28:40))

Comment: Put `public $timestamps = false;` in the top of your model.

Comment: Great to hear, Shawon! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Under: `$profile = new Profile(array('user_id'=>$uid, 'gender'=>$input['gender'], 'age'=>$input['age'], 'address'=>$input['address']));`

wrtite : `$profile->save();`

and the action? of `{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4')) !!}`

read this http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#form-model-binding